# Java start while loop without pausing current thread

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, while-loop

I have a GUI, in which when a button is clicked a while loop has to be started. But upon starting the while loop the GUI will be paused until the while loop has been terminated. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: I think you should provide some code.

Comment: Start your while loop in new thread.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose to generally prevent this from happening, you should create another `Thread` for lengthy calculations and then update the GUI through an EDT (using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable);`)

So in your case, when that button is pressed, it would look like this:

```
final Thread thread = new Thread(
        new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                while(condition){
                    .....
                }
                //update gui
            }
        }
);
thread.start();
```

Or if you are using Java 8, you can use lambdas:

```
final Thread thread = new Thread(
        () -> {
            while(condition){
                .....
            }
            //update gui
        }
);
thread.start();
```

You could remove that `while` loop by utilizing an `interface` acting as a listener of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your while loop in a Runnable and start that runnable with a thread. Note: `new Thread(r).run();` will run it on the same thread. The code below shouldn't.

```
 Runnable r = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         while(whatever){
         //do stuff
         }
     }
 }

 new Thread(r).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

As @kayton said, wrap your code in a Runnable.  ( or perhaps a Callable)

However, it quickly becomes hard to manage if you are constantly creating and starting you own threads all over your code.  Look into an ExecutorService or a SwingWorker instead.

Comment: Why the downvote?  At least have the courtesy and courage to explain.

Answer (score 0):

This is more on suggestion side from design perspective rather than solving the technical issue, i think pausing the GUI is not a good idea. You can show a spinning circle that would tell the user that there is some action going on behind the curtains. Pausing a screen may be annoying for a user.